# Materialize Menu does not work on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, materialize

I've made a WordPress theme by Materialize CSS Framework but I have an issue with navbar.
This is the image of my navbar right now : http://postimg.org/image/b27td128d/
As you see DropDown link has problem and is opened by default, also the same in Mobile screen.

Here the Navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav>
              <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="brand-logo"><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
                  </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you are using the default menu of wordpress (styling)... You should adapt the menu to be like the Materialize Menu

Comment: @LuisP.A. Can you explain what you mean & what i have to do?

Comment: You must custom you menu....check this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu (Change classes, hide, order, etc....)

Answer (score 0):

`wp_nav_menu` generates a list along with its `ul`. However, you can mention the ul classes and id in your menus separately like so,

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="brand-logo"><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down'
        ));
      ?>
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'menu_class' => 'side-nav',
          'menu_id' => 'mobile_demo'
        ));
      ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You can observe here that `menu_class` and `menu_id` correspond to a list's class and id respectively. You don't even need to use the `ul` tags.

Comment: Will show error for this lines:    <?php
      wp_nav_menu({
        'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down'
      });
      ?>

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed out specifying the array. Code corrected, try now please.

Comment: Still the same as my-own code minus now would not works on mobile screen.

Comment: Do you have a link where you've uploaded this?

Comment: For HTML version yes but for WP version no! cause still not completed.

Comment: If you can, kindly upload the WP version too so that I can debug

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing the same menu and i solved in this way: i set `items_wrap` with `<ul id="slide-out">` to re-create the same menu materialize structure and it seems to work:

```
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="logo"><?php bloginfo('title'); ?></a>
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down'
        ));
      ?>
      <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
          'menu_class' => 'side-nav',
          'menu_id' => 'mobilemenu',
          'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="slide-out" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'  
        ));
      ?>
      <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the Bootstrap walker that already existed and added some customisations to make it work with MaterialiseCSS. Seems to work fine, but I'm sure there are things that can be improved in the code since I'm not a big PHP user :)

https://github.com/eamonnmag/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that with your Wordpress Menu works with Materialize CSS (sub-menus), is by adding this line in your script:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

// Add class to ul parent
$('#primary-menu').addClass('hide-on-med-and-down');

// Add to sub menus unique ID
$( ".sub-menu" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass( "dropdown-content" );
    $(this).attr('id', 'dropdown' + index);
});

// Get li parents, identify which have sub-menus
$( "ul#primary-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('dropdown-button');
    $(this).attr('data-activates', 'dropdown' + index);
});

// Configure dropdown
$(".dropdown-button").dropdown({
    hover: false
});
});
```

Just look at the Materialize structure and replicate it in the Wordpress Menu ;)

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me : https://github.com/Kail0/wp-materialize-navwalker
in header.php

```
    <nav role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu' => 'Primary',
                        'theme_location'=>'Primary',
                        'container' => '', 
                        'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down',
                        'walker' => new wp_materialize_navwalker()
                    ));
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this code for reponsive

footer.php

```
    $(function() {

    elemSwap = function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 992) {

            $('.nav-wrapper.container > ul').attr("id", "nav-mobile");
            $('.nav-wrapper.container > ul').removeClass('right hide-on-med-and-down').addClass('side-nav');

            $('.drag-target').on('click', function() {
                $('.side-nav').removeAttr('style');
            });
            $('nav .button-collapse').click(function(event) {
                $('.side-nav').css({
                    "transform": "translateX(0%)"
                });
            });
            $('#menu-menu .dropdown-button.main-menu-item').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: false, // Activate on hover
                belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
                alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
            });
            // nested dropdown initialization
            $('#menu-menu .dropdown-button.sub-menu-item').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: false, // Activate on hover
                gutter: ($('.dropdown-content').width() * 3) / 3.05 + 3, // Spacing from edge
                belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
                alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
            });

        } else {
            $('.nav-wrapper.container > ul').attr("id", "menu-menu");
            $('.nav-wrapper.container > ul').removeClass('side-nav').addClass('right hide-on-med-and-down');
            // main dropdown initialization
            $('#menu-menu .dropdown-button.main-menu-item').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: true, // Activate on hover
                belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
                alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
            });
            // nested dropdown initialization
            $('#menu-menu .dropdown-button.sub-menu-item').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: true, // Activate on hover
                gutter: ($('.dropdown-content').width() * 3) / 3.05 + 3, // Spacing from edge
                belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
                alignment: 'left' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
            });
        }
    }

    elemSwap();

    $(window).resize(elemSwap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like below:

```
'menu_class'     => 'menu right hide-on-med-and-down'
```

The first word must be 'menu'.